# react leaflet measurement / ruler plugin

Tags: react-leaflet, measurement

I need a ruler for a React Leaflet app, however, all I can find are the plain leaflet plugins listed at
https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html.

I've tried to include all of them in my app but every single one of them has a different compatibility issue with current versions of React and/or Leaflet. Most of these plugins lack proper documentation and many are built for previous versions of leaflet.

Is there a modern measurement plugin or tool that I can use? or is there a well documented procedure to adapt the mentioned plugins to a React-Leaflet environment?

Comment: Which one you want to use?

Comment: @kboul I have not a particular preference. But let´s say this: http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.MeasureControl/

Comment: Leaflet 1.0 and higher is not supported for this library [source](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.MeasureControl/issues/16)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm talking about. All these libs have one issue or another. If you have any suggestion it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Leaflet-Ruler Plugin](https://github.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler) works only if you include the files locally (one css and one js), it cannot be used neither using npm nor cdn links (with the latter it should normally). If including the files locally is not a problem for you I can provide an example using react and react-leaflet.

Comment: @kboul I have no problem including local files in my app. Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @kboul It worked like a charm! Thanks for taking the time to put all this together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue what it was discussed in the comments, you can use [leaflet-ruler plugin](https://github.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler) but without cdns by placing the js and css files locally. I tried using cdns but I got some errors similar to what I would get if I had not imported the library properly.

Therefore go to https://github.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler/tree/master/src and copy paste the .css and .js files into two separate files in your React projec (see also the provided demo). Once you do that create a custom react-leaflet component and import the library's css and js file.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "./leaflet-ruler.css";
import "./leaflet-ruler";

export default function LeafletRuler() {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    L.control.ruler().addTo(map);
  }, [map]);

  return null;
}
```

Once you do that you are ready to use the library like this:

```
 <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
    ...
    <LeafletRuler />
 </MapContainer>
```

Note that in the sandbox plugin's button image is not displaying properly but in your local environment it should be ok.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3-measurement-ruler-plugin-leaflet-ruler-fzjts?file=/src/App.js:242-542)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation of a ruler for react-leaflet available at this GitHub repository: https://github.com/suwaloff/react-leaflet-ruler.

You can adapt it to your project or simply move the 'ruler' folder to your project.   [DEMO](https://suwaloff.github.io/react-leaflet-ruler/)

Answer (score 0):

With react-leaflet v4, this code worked for me. Thanks @kboul

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.measure' // from https://github.com/aprilandjan/leaflet.measure

const ShowMeasure = () => {
    var panelDiv = L.DomUtil.create('tiraLagAgua');
    if (L.Browser.chrome) {
        L.Browser.passiveEvents = true                                  
    }

    const map = useMap()
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map) {
            console.log("Não encontrou o mapa", map)
            return
        }
            L.control.measure({                                              
            position: 'topright',
            lineColor: 'red',
            lineWeight: 4
        }).addTo(map)
    }, [map])
    return null
}

export default ShowMeasure
```

And to call it:

```
<ShowMeasure />
```

Libraries that I used:

```
"leaflet": "^1.9.4",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-leaflet": "^4.2.1"
```